# Linear Algebra Videos

Tags: linear-algebra

There use to he a series on Khan academy about Linear algebra. It was more about the concepts rather than calculating the dot product or distance between points as an example. It wasn't done by Sal, does anyone know where to find them or what I am talking about?

I search for a while but couldn't find the series.

Comment: This is another great series that is all about concept instead of computation. It is also pretty short.
http://www.3blue1brown.com/essence-of-linear-algebra/

Comment: I am working on a set of linear algebra videos to accompany my book Linear Algebra Done Right. The first group of these videos should be available in a few weeks at http://www.linear.axler.net.

Comment: Thanks jnez71. I think I have seen some before. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your series but [here is the best playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8&itct=CCYQojAYACITCO2H-uKY2tICFaGDnAodzYcFEg%3D%3D&hl=en&gl=IN&client=mv-google)

Comment: Do you know what "$18.02$ Linear Algebra" stands for? I am used to undergrad classes being labeled by numbers between 1000 and 5000, I have no idea how advanced 18.02 is.

Comment: @Ovi $18$ is the designation for the math department at MiT.  The specific courses in the mathematics department themselves then have a two or three digit number following the decimal.  Currently linear algebra is labeled at 18.06 on their course catalog and 18.02 is now calculus 2.  In either case, it appears to be freshman level undergraduate material.

Comment: @Ovi: your question is easily answered by looking at the website of MIT's math department. 18.06 is the hand-held, more applied and computational version of linear algebra, mostly for non-math students. 18.700 is the more advanced, proof-based undergraduate linear algebra course.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you